how replace text with match case irrespective of position in a document

right now
i am setting bookmark at beginning of document at line 1
i am on line 23, to replace text, i will jump to bookmark
edit- execute command- replace-string
text is replaced
i want to replace at once irrespective of my position in document
i have activated "line numbers in mode line" to check for lines in document


You might want to read an introduction to Emacs (or perhaps better, go through the Emacs tutorial): start Emacs and type C-h t - then go through the tutorial from beginning to end. That will clarify a lot of things for you and it will also give you some familiarity with the terminology that you should use when you describe a problem in this forum or elsewhere.  You should also "lurk" a bit on the site to learn the customs of its inhabitants before you ask questions: browse some questions that look interesting to you, read the answers and see how far you can understand them, then read ...

... the topics in the help site: click on the ? icon in the upper right hand corner of the page and  read as much as you can. In particular, read How to ask a good question. But even that assumes that you know how to ask a question: that turns out to be surprisingly difficult for many people. In the case of this question, one of the problems is that there no question: we can make a guess based on the title, that the penultimate bullet is the question and every other bullet is describing the problem, but it is not clear - so ...

... make it clear: state the problem as clearly as possible, add whatever details you think might be relevant (like the last bullet - it's probably not relevant, but it's OK to include it if you think it is helpful) and then end it with your question.  In describing the problem, be as specific as possible: a good example is the best way to describe it, particularly when you are not sure of the terminology to use. Show the contents of a simple file (including some indication of the cursor position) and then show what you want the result to be afterwards (including the cursor position).

BTW, welcome to the site!


i want to replace at once irrespective of my position in document

Use either of these before calling replace-string:

M-< (runs the command beginning-of-buffer)
C-xh (runs the command mark-whole-buffer)

